# TCL NS-2 error: 'Error when calling class $cls: $args" $...".'

Tags: tcl, ns2

I have installed NS-2.35 in Ubuntu 22.04.1. I am running a TCL code (which is working fine in my friend's machine) but I am getting the following error:

```
num_nodes is set 101
INITIALIZE THE LIST xListHead
ns: _o1096 Public: 
    (_o1096 cmd line 1)
    invoked from within
"_o1096 cmd Public"
    invoked from within
"catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
set cls [$self info class]
global errorInfo
set savedInfo $errorInfo
error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
    (procedure "_o1096" line 2)
    (SplitObject unknown line 2)
    invoked from within
"_o1096 Public"
```

My main tcl file does not have a `Public` keyword. However, the main file loads another file, in which I have categorized my nodes in three types: public, private and govt.

```
$ns at 0.0 "[$n49 set ragent_] Public"
#$ns at 0.0 "[$n38 set ragent_] Private"
$ns at 0.0 "[$n59 set ragent_] Govt"
```

I have 29 Public nodes:

```
$ns at 0.0 "[$n1 set ragent_] Public"
$ns at 0.0 "[$n2 set ragent_] Public"
$ns at 0.0 "[$n3 set ragent_] Public"
```

26 Private ones:

```
$ns at 0.0 "[$n30 set ragent_] Private"
$ns at 0.0 "[$n31 set ragent_] Private"
$ns at 0.0 "[$n32 set ragent_] Private"
```

Similarly, 2 Govt. nodes:

```
$ns at 0.0 "[$n58 set ragent_] Govt"
$ns at 0.0 "[$n59 set ragent_] Govt"
```

But the error is only in `Public` type. Why so? How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Most of that stack trace is just OTcl internals, and NS2 is the *only* known user of OTcl in the wild. In any case, the *immediate* problem seems to be in the `Public` method... whatever that does and whatever triggers the problem. The `make` trace isn't helpful in the slightest; it just says that it did nothing in various places. (It's usual to run `make all` as non-root and then only `sudo make install` afterwards.)

Comment: Hi @DonalFellows, thank you for pointing it out. I have edited my question and added more relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I have finally found a [solution](https://ramakrishnamundugar.blogspot.com/2013/04/error-while-adding-new-protocol.html).
The problem was with how I was running this code.
After updating AODV and common folder files, I had to recompile the source using the following commands:

```
> ./configure
> make clean
> make
> sudo make install
```

This worked for me, I hope it helps other people too.